# Where is the java.security file located on Windows?

Tags: java, windows, java-8, java-7

I need to locate and edit the `java.security` file on a Windows 7 host.  Where is it located in a default Oracle JRE installation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing java security file in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697451/changing-java-security-file-in-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should find it in `JRE_HOME\lib\security` knowing that by default `JRE_HOME` should be `c:\Program Files\Java\jre${version-id}`

Answer (score 5):

For the Oracle JRE, on my Windows 7 system `java.security` is in the following location:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security
```

By the way for the JDK, should you need it, it's in:

```
C:\Program Files\Java\<jdk_version>\jre\lib\security
```

e.g. `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_40\jre\lib\security`

Answer (score 1):

[https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/PolicyFiles.html)

```
Policy file locations are specified in the security properties file, which is located at
    java.home/lib/security/java.security  (Solaris/Linux)
    java.home\lib\security\java.security  **(Windows)**
```